Fabric.js in node doesnt support italic and bold
I'm using fabric.js in node. when i exporting image from fabric canvas,the font styles with italic and bold doesnt work.any idea how to solve this problem?(https://i.sstatic.net/B9v4S.jpg)
I've tried everything i could, and i looked some infomation on goole but none of them helps.
   t.set({
        fontSize:t.fontSize * canvasRitao,
       left: t.left * canvasRitao,
       width: t.text.length * t.fontSize,
       text:'text try',
       fontStyle:'italic'
      });

